# Laravel thinks jQuery is always GET request method

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, request

Laravel thinks that jQuery is sending a GET request even though it is not.

I have confirmed this via the `request()->method()` function.

Controller function:

```
public function fields($vertical_id = null, $lead_id = null)
{
    echo request()->method();
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#vertical_id', function () {
    $.post('http://myapp.local/leads/fields/1/2', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::any('leads/fields/{vertical_id?}/{lead_id?}', 'LeadController@fields')->name('leads.fields');
```

Notice I had to use `any` because when I tried to use `post` it threw a method not allowed exception. My console is showing `GET` every single time I make this request.

How do I get Laravel to realize jQuery is sending a POST not a GET?

Comment: You sure it wasn't sending an `OPTIONS` request? Look in your browser's _Network_ console

Comment: Do you have other routes declared with same signature using get method?

Comment: This is hilarious. When I remove the parameters from the URL it now thinks that it is a POST. I'm guessing that using conditional parameters in the route causes Laravel to change the request to a GET automatically.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using a path in your client-side scripts instead of a fully-qualified URL. It will avoid potential cross-domain issues and it makes your app portable. For example `$.post('/leads/...`

Comment: could it be conflicting with other routes?

Answer (score 0):

Remove name in last of route.

```
Route::any('leads/fields/{vertical_id?}/{lead_id?}', 'LeadController@fields');
```

Try this code in route.php file